# How to use a custom block template when the block is embedded in a panel pane?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks, panels

I have a block that I have templated and want to use in and out of a panel layout in various parts of my site.

So to template the block I opted to install the block_machine_name module which gives a good anchor point for the template so the block id is not relied upon (as this changes between my dev and prod sites).

Then I theme the block and it works just great using a template name like block--sweet-name.tpl.php

Then I also use the block in a panels layout and things start to go wrong.
The block template is now ignored.

So I am trying to find a way to get panels embedded block to respect block templates.

Is this possible?

Comment: I overlooked trying to template the block using the block--block-7.tpl.php style templates and this does work in and out of panels. However I still would prefer to use the machine name style template for both so now I need to figure out how to get this working with panels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use the block template in panels, make sure you choose the style from the panels option to be "Systems block".

[image: Panel Style]

This lets you use block--sweet-name.tpl.php.

Comment: Nice one! I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have machine name based block templates and you need to also use non machine name block templates as in this example then you can just make a non machine name block template that includes the machine name one. Though still not ideal it could.

```
<?php
    //use the mchine name block
    $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'myTheme');
    include($path."/templates/block--sweet-name.tpl.php");
?>
```

If anyone has a better solution though I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying this little backport from Drupal 8.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2307505

It will show you all the templates and their suggestions which surround the output of your block.  And in this case, it will likely be a pane template.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * panels-pane--block--sweet-module-sweet-name.tpl.php
   * panels-pane--block.tpl.php
   x panels-pane.tpl.php
-->
```